# How to delete a particular row from table by clicking button Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, html-table

I am trying to delete a particular row by clicking button from that row which is in for loop,but its deleting all the rows of that table.

Here is my Html code:

```
<table id="mytable" class="table table-bordred table-striped">
    <tbody id="del">
        <tr *ngFor="let cart of modalData">
            <td>
                <div style="display:inline-flex;">
                    <div style="margin-left:10px;">
                        <p class="font_weight" style="font-size:13px;">{{cart.ExamName}}</p>
                        <p>{{cart.Categoryname}}|{{cart.CompanyName}}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div style="margin-top: 32px;">
                    <p class="font_weight" style="font-size:13px;"></p> <span class="font_weight" style="font-size: 13px;"> {{cart.Amount| currency :'USD':'true'}} </span> </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div style="margin-top: 19px;">
                    <button class="button_transparent" (click)="Delete(cart)"> delete </button>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr> </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is my Component:

```
public loadData() {       

                let transaction = new TransactionalInformation();
                this.myCartService.GetExamOrderForCart()
                    .subscribe(response => this.getDataOnSuccess(response),
                    response => this.getDataOnError(response));          

        }

    getDataOnSuccess(response) {       
        this.modalData = response.Items;
        }
```

This is my delete method:

```
public Delete(response) {
     this.myCartService.updateExamOrder(response)
     .subscribe(response => this.getDataOnSuccessForDelete(response),
     response => this.getDataOnErrorForDelete(response));
}
```

Please help me to do, How to delete only one row from table?

Comment: You mean one by one, from top to down?

Comment: Can you post your Delete method?

Comment: public Delete(response) {
        
        this.myCartService.updateExamOrder(response)
            .subscribe(response => this.getDataOnSuccessForDelete(response),
            response => this.getDataOnErrorForDelete(response));
       
       
    }This is my delete method

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add `index` in *ngFor :

```
<tr *ngFor="let cart of modalData;let i = index">
```

Then, pass the index in the method:

```
<button class="button_transparent" (click)="delete(i)"> delete </button>
```

And finally:

```
delete(i){
  this.modalData.splice(i,1);
}
```

Comment: Yes I got it,Thank you

Answer (score 3):

you can do this:

`<button class="button_transparent" (click)="delete(cart)"> delete </button>`

then

```
delete(item){
    this. modalData = this. modalData.filter(item => item.id !== id);
    this.modalData.push();}
```

here you are creating a new list without the element that you want to delete.