# how to get span value in angular 4 in onclick event?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-template

I'm working on angular 4 and I'm trying to implement functionality where I can remove tag by clicking on the cross button. so below is my code :

Component.hmtl

```
<ul id="ul_top_hypers">
      <li *ngFor="let hero of technologies">
          <span class="badge badge-pill badge-primary"  >{{ hero }}<i class="fa fa-cross-circle-right fa-lg" (click)="removeTag1($event)"></i></span>
        </li>
 </ul>
```

Component.ts

```
 removeTag(event: any) {
    console.log(event.target.parentNode.value);
    console.log(event.target.value);
   }
```

I wanted to get span value of every `li` element by clicking on cross button so that I can remove that perticular tag. But I'm getiing `undefind` in console.

any help is too appreciable.

Comment: What's a "span value"?

Comment: Check this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45757633/how-to-delete-a-particular-row-from-table-in-angular-2-by-clicking-delete-button/45757794#45757794

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd just use the index

```
  <ul id="ul_top_hypers">
      <li *ngFor="let hero of technologies;let i=index">
          <span class="badge badge-pill badge-primary"  >{{ hero }}<i class="fa fa-cross-circle-right fa-lg" (click)="removeTag1(i)"></i></span>
        </li>
 </ul>
```

by adding `;let i=index` the index becomes available and
`(click)="removeTag1(i)"` passes the index to the `removeTag(...)` method. If you pass the value, you first need to find the value in the array before you can delete it, if you pass the index, you know immediately what array item to delete.

Comment: Thanks @Gunter. it's wokring. I'm new in angular 4. :) Thanks again.

Comment: @KULDEEPBISEN if the answer solved your problem, then select it so your question is closed

Answer (score 1):

I get information from my mediawiki and display it in a div in an angular2+ html form.

```
<div class="wiki" (click)="getWikiPage($event)">
    <div [innerHtml]="pageContent"> </div>
</div>
```

The mediawiki generated TC looks like this:

```
<span class="toctext">Welcome</span>
```

In the component I get the information about the span value:

```
getWikiPage(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    if (e.srcElement.nodeName == 'SPAN') {
      console.log('Wiki TC span value: ', e.srcElement.innerHTML)
    }
    return false;
}
```